# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo error

Tags: java, android

In the start my app was running normally in the start but after I updated it started crashing all of a  sudden when i checked in the logcat I got the following error
Logcat

```
Process: com.example.deliveryapp, PID: 6208
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deliveryapp/com.example.deliveryapp.DriversMapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.deliveryapp:layout/activity_drivers_maps: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.deliveryapp:layout/activity_drivers_maps: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.deliveryapp:layout/activity_drivers_maps: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.deliveryapp:layout/activity_drivers_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.deliveryapp:layout/activity_drivers_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060016 type #0x3 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:827)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.at.h(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):7)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):15)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):21)
        at cy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zae.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
2021-08-07 12:53:53.497 6208-6208/com.example.deliveryapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.example.deliveryapp.databinding.ActivityDriversMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityDriversMapsBinding.java:65)
        at com.example.deliveryapp.databinding.ActivityDriversMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityDriversMapsBinding.java:59)
        at com.example.deliveryapp.DriversMapsActivity.onCreate(DriversMapsActivity.java:74)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and from here I understood that the error is in this line

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityDriversMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

but this used to work in the start
and now it doesn't run

Edit:
This is my XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DriversMapsActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_customer_maps" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Customerinfo"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:id="@+id/Profile"
            android:padding="20sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Customername"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Orderdone"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/Call"
                />
            
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Alsoo when i recompile it does working normally
but after sometimes this happens again

Comment: There seems to be an error inflating the fragment class in your activity_drivers_maps.xml. Could you paste the code of this XML file?

Comment: @JornRigter i added it

Comment: What is line 12? I can't count that high.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice line 12 of fragment?

Comment: I mean of the XML file. The output says the error is on line 12. That's where you should start.

Comment: You should also look through the stack trace for a reference to code that you wrote. This will give you a place to look for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have something to do with the way you initialize your `SupportMapFragment` in your fragment in the XML (where the inflating error is thrown). The way [Google shows it](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) is different from the way you initialize it. Instead of `android:name` they use `class`:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Heyy i am facing the exact same issue and i tried this but it didn't work for me